# Expanding height of all cards in row when expanding one

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create cards in a row with dropdown. But when one card collapses, height of all other card changes corresponding the first one. How can I prevent that? I want to expand only the selected card. Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row mr-0 ml-0">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">First card <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-x info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></i></h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">9/10/2020</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">t1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Price</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Second card <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-x info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></i></h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">9/10/2020</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">t1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Price</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you do to collapse a card? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as I think you need to edit your question in line with that.

Comment: Try using the card-group class https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#card-layout Maybe that will help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this class `align-items-start` to `<div class="row mr-0 ml-0">`. This will prevent the height of all cards from expansion when expanding one.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row align-items-start mr-0 ml-0">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">First card <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-x info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></i></h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">9/10/2020</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">t1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Price</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Second card <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-x info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></i></h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">9/10/2020</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">t1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">t4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Price</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```